# How to add a column family in system_auth keyspace in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I have a live cluster (Cassandra 2.0.9, CQL spec 3.1.1) using `AllowAllAuthenticator` at the moment, and I want to switch it to `PasswordAuthenticator` **without** downtime, so I'm trying to create the system_auth  key space and its column families manually.

However, Cassandra seems to prevent users from doing any changes in the system_auth key space.  This is what I got:

```
cqlsh:system_auth> CREATE TABLE credentials (
           ...   username text,
           ...   options map<text, text>,
           ...   salted_hash text,
           ...   PRIMARY KEY (username)
           ... ) WITH gc_grace_seconds=7776000;
Bad Request: Cannot CREATE <keyspace system_auth>
```

Is there a way around this problem?  The Datastax Enterprise version has an authenticator `TransitionalAuthenticator` that allows no down time transition to `PasswordAuthenticator`.  Is there any chance it can be used in the open source version?  Thanks

Comment: Me too facing same problem? can anyone please help